How do I download a pdf being passed as varbinary buffer data to front end?
Im currently working on a project using node.js, express and mssql. I have a table that stores all pdf files in varbinary format. I am retrieving this data from the table and creating an object named document and passing it to a ejs vew. Here are all the properties in that object document:
   id: 2,
   policy_number: 5353535,
   policy_type: 'Motorcycle',
   status: [ null, null, 'T-Docs Requested' ],
   address: '9000 Logan st',
   effective_date: null,
   company: 'Progressive',
   bi_liability_limits: 1000,
   pd_liability_limits: null,
   pip_liability_limits: null,
   bi_liability_deductibles: null,
   pd_liability_deductibles: null,
   pip_liability_deductibles: null,
   household_id: 2,
   guest_deductible: 20,
   guest_liability: 20,
   uw_action_id: [ 53, 53 ],
   request_type: 108,
   assigned_to: '2',
   created_on: 2024-04-24T18:43:16.543Z,
   due_date: 2024-05-01T18:43:16.543Z,
   created_by: '1',
   policy_id: 2,
   uw_action_documents_id: 35,
   additional_documents: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 37 0d 0a 25 b5 b5 b5 b5 0d 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 0a 3c 3c 2f 54 79 70 65 2f 43 61 74 61 6c 6f 67 2f 50 61 67 65 73 20 32 20 ... 32052 more bytes>,
   endorsements: null,
   proof_of_home_ownership: null,
   drivers_license: null,
   fl_dl_check: null

As you can see additional_documents contains the raw binary data for the pdf. On the front end I am displaying the data as follows:
<tr  >
    <td><%= document.policy_number %> <br> <%= document.policy_type %></td>
    <td><%= document.status %></td>
    <td>UM/UIM <br> FORM</td>
    <td><% if (document.additional_documents !== null) { %>
        <a href="#" onclick="downloadFile('<%= document.additional_documents %>', test.pdf)">✅Additional Docs</a>
      <% } else { %>
        ❌No additional docs
      <% } %>
        <br>
        <%= document.endorsements !== null ? '✅Endorsements' : '❌No endorsements' %> 
        <br>
        <%= document.proof_of_home_ownership !== null ? '✅Home Ownership' : '❌No home ownership' %> 
        <br>
        <%= document.drivers_license !== null ? '✅DL License' : '❌No DL' %> 
        <br>
        <%= document.fl_dl_check !== null ? '✅DL License Chcek' : '❌No DL check' %> 
        <br>
        <%= document.created_on.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }) %></td>
    <td>✍️️</td>
</tr> ````

I have two functions in script one of them is commented out because I was using it to test downloading raw varbinary text files being passed to the client side. It works perfectly fine with text files. The second function is me trying to attempt to download raw varbinary pdf files being passed to the client side:
  /*  function downloadFile(fileData) {
        console.log(fileData)
      // Convert the varbinary data to a Blob object
      const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
  
      // Create a URL for the Blob object
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
      // Create a link element
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
  
      // Set the filename for the downloaded file
      link.download = 'filename.txt';
  
      // Append the link to the body
      document.body.appendChild(link);
  
      // Trigger the click event on the link
      link.click();
  
      // Remove the link from the body
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } */
    function downloadFile(base64Data, fileName) {
    // Convert the base64 data to a Blob object
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 512) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 512);
        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: 'application/pdf' });

    // Create a URL for the Blob object
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create a link element
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;

    // Set the filename for the downloaded file
    link.download = fileName;

    // Append the link to the body
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // Trigger the click event on the link
    link.click();

    // Remove the link from the body
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
  </script>```

When I click the additional docs a href link i get console.logged this error in the browser:
```downloadFile('%PDF-1.7
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en) /StructTreeRoot 15 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 27 0 R/ViewerPreferences 28 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 12 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS10 10 0 R/GS11 11 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 226>>
stream
x���Ak1�{ ���`v&q7  ,]��R�)=��S���0k+X�Kk�c�5�e�-��({�t-�n��C�tV�S
R�?��"��k|��x{@'�4J�=2����Rp�V+�9,y5ֈ�)7o��R)��ֹ����5�u�]J�/�Pť~2�s��)�\?'  1�ӽV&��;G�)coXH��8����  �v���ɩ>~���� ԋ
G?x~
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/BCDEEE+Calibri/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts 6 0 R/ToUnicode 23 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
[ 7 0 R] ```


Yeah i think it is being extracted as simple text because when I tried with text files "downloadFile(" would contain the contents of the text file. I dont know if storing the pdf in the database would be the best approach maybe storing the pdfs in the file system storage would be a better approach?

Well I'm using azure. So I think using azure blob services to directly download files in their correct format would be way easier than figuring out how to convert files from hex into a readable file format. I could store the blob names in the database instead and use that as a reference to the blob's in azure and have them directly download from the blob storage.
